# MPAndroidChart wrong values / performance issue

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to change library for graph / charts but after change has problem with performance.

Like You can see on the image values on chart are incorrect.

Data is coming fast maybe is it a library limitation or I'm doing something wrong?

[image]

Code:

```
lineData.addEntry(new Entry(linearAccelerationData.body.timestamp, (float) arrayData.x), 0);
lineData.addEntry(new Entry(linearAccelerationData.body.timestamp, (float) arrayData.y), 1);
lineData.addEntry(new Entry(linearAccelerationData.body.timestamp, (float) arrayData.z), 2);
lineData.notifyDataChanged();

// let the chart know it's data has changed
mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // limit the number of visible entries
    mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(150);

   // move to the latest entry
   mChart.moveViewToX(lineData.getEntryCount());
```

Logs:

```
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1233, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.15314611792564392, "y": -0.52404689788818359, "z": 10.023892402648926}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1310, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.098109230399131775, "y": -0.53122562170028687, "z": 10.052606582641602}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1387, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.14836029708385468, "y": -0.5431901216506958, "z": 10.047821044921875}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1464, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.15793193876743317, "y": -0.52404689788818359, "z": 10.114822387695312}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1540, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.18664683401584625, "y": -0.52643978595733643, "z": 10.071749687194824}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1617, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.14357449114322662, "y": -0.55754756927490234, "z": 10.074143409729004}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1694, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.13160994648933411, "y": -0.49772489070892334, "z": 9.9951772689819336}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1771, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.1411815732717514, "y": -0.56951212882995605, "z": 10.138751983642578}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1848, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.11725249886512756, "y": -0.51447522640228271, "z": 10.026285171508789}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 1924, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.15793193876743317, "y": -0.55994051694869995, "z": 10.131572723388672}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 2001, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.13878867030143738, "y": -0.5336185097694397, "z": 10.023892402648926}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 2607, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": 0, "y": 4.7906022071838379, "z": 8.6312198638916016}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 2683, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": 0.0047858161851763725, "y": 4.7331724166870117, "z": 8.7795801162719727}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 2760, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.0023929080925881863, "y": 4.4699521064758301, "z": 8.5929327011108398}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 2837, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.0095716323703527451, "y": 4.8863182067871094, "z": 8.5546464920043945}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 2914, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": 0.023929081857204437, "y": 4.8504247665405273, "z": 8.6934347152709961}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 2991, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": 0, "y": 4.8576035499572754, "z": 8.6455764770507812}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 3067, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.014357448555529118, "y": 4.8743538856506348, "z": 8.6695060729980469}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 3144, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": 0.0047858161851763725, "y": 4.862389087677002, "z": 8.5642185211181641}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 3221, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.0095716323703527451, "y": 4.8552103042602539, "z": 8.6479701995849609}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 3298, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": -0.014357448555529118, "y": 4.8671751022338867, "z": 8.549860954284668}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
{"Body": {"Timestamp": 3375, "ArrayAcc": [{"x": 0.0071787242777645588, "y": 4.8815326690673828, "z": 8.6192550659179688}]}, "Uri": "ECKIA1730841/Meas/Acc/13", "Method": "PUT"}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214094/passing-current-time-in-milliseconds-to-mpchart-breaks-it/46252461#46252461

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: your problem got solved?

Comment: I'm losing precision but I think can handle this so Yes it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dividing timestamps by for ex. 100 solving problem.**

We are losing some precision but looks like for now this is library limitation.